# Rapidflow importing issues

Tags: import

I am having the following issues with using rapidflow for importing products into Magento and I was hoping someone could advise.

1. After uploading configurable products, the inputs in the configurable options container within the product view on the frontend are inactive (you can't select any options).
2. Several products have the same main image and a small image. It is uploading the main image, but not declaring it as the small image as well (same values in both fields).

Help would be appreciated! Thank you!

The following files in the zip file below contain an example of the product import where I am having trouble with the small_image and the CPSA that is not yielding inactive inputs on the front end.
http://alluringassets.com/caitlin/rapidflowhelp.zip

Comment: What happens when you try to edit the configurable product in the backend right after import? Does it make you select super attributes? Could you also give an example of the data file you are importing?

Comment: No it is successfully selecting attributes during the CPSA import. Hold on I'll post

Comment: Have you tried contacting Unirgy support?

Comment: I emailed them. I figured I'd see if any of you had experience with it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if in admin configurable products are associated, then the connection is correct.
There is something else that should be wrong, like quantities of simple products for example. I would rephrase the question as why would Magento display inactive inputs for configurable options.
As for image, any attribute should be explicitly imported to have an effect. In Magento image, small_image and thumbnail are attributes which are assigned as values image paths. As such you should provide value for each one even if the value is the same.

Comment: Nothing like getting tech support from *actual* Unirgy devs on Magento.SE!

Comment: The simple has quanitity of 10000 and is "in stock". small_image is specified. Can you update that field through import, or would you have to delete products and run the import again? Okay, will start seperate question.

Comment: Okay, I think I know the inputs issue, and yes its unrelated!